# When i recurse the following code on function prime the program crashes what is wrong in my code?

Tags: c++, recursion

Whenever I try to recurse in the function prime, my program crashes at that step.  I think the problem is passing the function small as a recursion.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int smallest(int n) {
   for( int x = 2 ; x <= n/2 ;  x++){
     if (n%x==0) {
        return x;
     }
     else {
        return 0;
     }
   }
}

int prime(int n, int(*small)(int)) {
  int factor;
  if (n == 1){
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    factor = n % small(n);
    cout << small(n) << endl;
    return prime(factor , small);
  }
}

int main() {
  prime(50 , &smallest);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `prime` function does **a terrible thing** when `n` is `0`.

Comment: When `smallest` is passed a prime number it returns 0.  `n % 0` is undefined.

Comment: but when i pass n to be 50 shouldnt the program run?

Comment: Yes until `factor` becomes prime.  Single step your program, I can't at the moment as I am on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, when `small` returns `0`, you continue recursing when you shouldn't. This can be solved with a small update to your base case:

```
if (n <= 1){
    return 0 ;
}
```

Furthermore, it's worth pointing out that as it stands, your `prime` function will **never call itself more than once**. When you call `smallest`, you are guaranteed to get a prime number!